# Validate uniqueness of many to many association in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

Say I have **Project**, that is in many-to-many association with **Tag**. I'm using *has_many through* so I have separate join model.

How do I create validation, that checks uniqueness of join model? Now I have only

```
has_many :tags, :through => :taggings, :uniq => true
```

But that doesn't validate on save.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [validates_associated](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#M002114).

That should, I believe, allow the join model validations to run before saving. So in your case:

```
class Project
   has many :tags, :through => :taggings
   validates_associated :taggings
end

class Taggings
   belongs_to :tags

   #your validations here....
end

class Tag
   has_many :taggings
end
```

Answer (score 16):

I think what you want is [validates_uniqueness_of](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#M001400):

```
class Taggings
  belongs_to :tags
  validates_uniqueness_of :tag_id, :scope => :project_id
end
```

This is what I'm using, and works well.

Comment: Hi, but when I add a duplicated tag to a project with `project.tags << Tag.find_or_create_by_name "Design"` it raises a `ActiveRecord::ValidateError` exception, is there a way to silently fails on duplication while adding the tag without problems when the tag is new? What is the best way to manage this? Thanks

Comment: There's probably a simpler way to do it, but I think this would add only non-duplicates: `design_tags = Tag.find_or_create_by_name "Design"
    project.tags << design_tags.reject{ |tag| project.tags.include?(tag) }`