# How to fail validation when there is no corresponding record (many to many relationship)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two models `Link` and `Feed` with many-many relationship (has many :through `LinkFeed` join model).
Each Link should belong to 1 or more Feeds. So I want to allow creating Link with (because there is corresponding Feed record):

```
@feed = Feed.create(name: "Test Feed")
@feed.links.create!(url: "http://google.com")
```

And fail to create link with simple `Link.create!(url: "http://google.com")` because it doesn't have corresponding Feed record. How can I do this?

Edit:
I added this validation:

```
validate do
  errors.add(:base, "Must have at least one feed") unless feeds.size > 0
end
```

But now both examples fail with this error :/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `must not be null` condition to your foreign key `feed_id`.

```
class Link

  validates :feed_id, :presence => true
  ...
end
```

This would keep records created without a association with feed to fail.

EDIT:

Here, two answers about validation in many-to-many relashionships.
[Validate uniqueness of many to many association in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421544/validate-uniqueness-of-many-to-many-association-in-rails)
[Correct implementation of many-to-many in Ruby on Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7322230/correct-implementation-of-many-to-many-in-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: So do I need to have feed_id in Link model?

Comment: Well, link is related to a feed, right? So i think that the Link should hold a reference to the Feed.

Comment: Oh, didn't know that. So you have a `feeds_links` table?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28681/discussion-between-marcin-doliwa-and-murifox)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a combination of validates_presence_of :feed_id, and [validates_associated](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_associated) on your Link class. `validates_associated` ensures that the Feed is a valid object as well.